# How do i use two Images (as buttons) within one form (asp classic)

Tags: asp-classic

I have a form within a repeating region that I would like to have two buttons on.

I currently have one button (an image) that submits the form and generates a preview of the record. I would like to add a second button to the same form that performs a different function. I have assigned different names and values to each of the image buttons but how do I retrieve that value and either do a corresponding response.redirect or perform an additional function?

I know in PHP you can use the `$_GET["getvar"];` or `$_post["getvar"];` but i am using classic asp.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I've been away from classic asp for awhile now, but if I remember correctly, an image button will not pass a value back to the server.  I'd suggest using a regular submit button and style it.  Otherwise, you could use regular images with onclick events, and a bit of javascript to set a value in a hidden field for which "button" you clicked.

Answer (score 1):

example for you

```
<input type="hidden" name="PageAction" value="" />
<input type="image" name="button1" src="imgage1.jpg" onclick="this.form.PageAction.value='function1';this.form.submit();" />
<input type="image" name="button2" src="imgage2.jpg" onclick="this.form.PageAction.value='function2';this.form.submit();" />
```

then you can retrive the value of request("PageAction") to seperate diffrent actions,like:

```
    if request("PageAction")="function1" then
        call function1()
    elseif request("PageAction")="function2" then
        call function2()
    end if
```

Answer (score 0):

Request.QueryString("getvar") is the equivalent of $_get and Request.Form("getvar") is the equivalent of $_post.

Where *getvar* is the name of the button, it will return the value.